# 404 Error when trying to link to another page flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to build a multi page web app with flask, but when I click on one of the links from my index page, a 404 error is thrown. I've checked through the flask docs and can't work out why it's happening.

Any advice or guidance would be massively appreciated!

HTML

```
   <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="second_page">second_page</a></li>

        <!--<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>-->
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Python Code

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('homepage.html')

@app.route("/second_page.html")
def mrege_requests():
    return render_template('second_page.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True,port=2001)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<li class="active"><a href="second_page">second_page</a></li>
```

points to `/second_page`, while you have route for:

```
@app.route("/second_page.html")
```

Either change your link to:

```
<li class="active"><a href="second_page.html">second_page</a></li>
```

Or fix your route:

```
@app.route("/second_page")
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

As the `href` attribute points to `second_page`, the route must be

```
@app.route("/second_page")
def mrege_requests():
    return render_template('second_page.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the url_for() function in your template. This function converts a *function name* (not a route!) to a valid URL.

Try something along the lines of:

```
<li class="active"><a href="{{url_for('mrege_requests')}}">second_page</a></li>
```

The relevant documentation can be found here:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#url-building