# Linking to another page within a website with Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to make a website, and right now I'm just trying to make sure I can get the basic parts working.

When I click the link on my index page that should redirect me to my test page, I get a 404 Not Found Error.

I've done a bunch of searching, trying to figure out how to fix my problem, but nothing is working. One question that looks like it should be an exact fix to my problem is [404 Error when trying to link to another page flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41739142/404-error-when-trying-to-link-to-another-page-flask), but I'm still getting my error after trying to change my href in test_link.html to match my route in flaskApp.py or trying url_for in test_link.html. I'm not sure what else to try.

Any help would be appreciated.

flaskApp.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, redirect, render_template, request, 
url_for

# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")

def get_index():
    return render_template('index.html')

app.route("/test_link")
def test_link():
    return render_template('test_link.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>hello</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Index Page</h1>

    <p>
        This is a test <a href="test_link">link</a>
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

test_link.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>hello</title>
</head>

<body>
    test link
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed `@` before `app.route("/test_link")` and your route didn't register. That's why you have `404`

Comment: I spent all afternoon trying to figure that out... Thanks for the quick response

Comment: No need to thank just mark it as correct answer :).